# In value of two definite integral in equal, then comment on root of equation

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Let $a,b,c$ be non-zero real numbers such that

$$\int_{0}^{1} (1+\cos ^8x)(ax^2+bx+c)dx=\int_{0}^{2} (1+\cos ^8x)(ax^2+bx+c)dx$$, then the equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ has (choose the correct option)

$1.$ No root in $(0,2)$

$2.$ Atleast one root in $(0,2)$

$3.$ Both roots in $(0,2)$

Could someone give me slight hint to solve this problem?

Comment: First, note that the above can be written as $\int_1^2 p(x) q(x) dx$ where $p(x) \ge 1$ and $q$ is the quadratic in question. If $q$ has no roots in $(0,2)$ then it does not change sign there.

Comment: @copper.hat SO for integral to be $0$ quadratic will have atleast one root in $(1,2)$ . Am I correct?

Comment: Correct, otherwise there could not be equality.

Comment: Since$ \int_{1}^{2} (1+\cos ^8x)(ax^2+bx+c)dx=0$ and since $1+\cos ^8x>0$ on $(1,2)$ then $ax^2+bx+c$ must have at least one root in $(1,2)\subset(0,2)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it has been noted above, the conditions imply that
\begin{equation*} \tag{$*$}
\int_1^2 (1+\cos^8 x)(ax^2+bx+c)\,dx=0.
\end{equation*}
Since $1+\cos^8 x \ge 1$ in $[1,2],$ there must be a root of the quadratic function $ax^2+bx+c$ in $(1,2).$ On the other hand, $(*)$ implies that
$$
Aa+Bb+Cc=0
$$
where $A,B,C$ are real numbers with $C \ne 0.$ Hence
$$
c=\alpha a+\beta b
$$
for some $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbf R.$ In effect, given any $a,b$ such that $a \ne 0,$ the function $ax^2+bx+c$ satisfies $(*)$ for a suitable $c.$ Now take *positive* $a,b,$ and define $c$ accordingly. As we now know, the corresponding function $q(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ has a root in $(1,2),$ hence its discriminant $\Delta$ is positive. But then $q(x)$ has also a *negative* root, namely
$$
\frac{-b-\sqrt\Delta}{2a} < 0.
$$
Thus it is impossible in general to have both roots in $(0,2),$ whence 2 is the correct answer.